# Are there any known bulk superinsulators?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, superconductivity, insulators

I recently learned about [superinsulators](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superinsulator). Basically materials which exhibit an abrupt phase transition to becoming perfectly resistive.

The wiki article reveals that this phenomenon is exhibited in thin titanium nitride films as well as Indium Oxide, and NbTiN films. I guess my question is, is the “film” aspect here important? Can a bulk material become a superinsulator ever or is it necessary that this be a very thin film/layer.

I dont claim to know too much about physics but some searching on scholar.google reveals that 2D superconductor is a term very frequently present with superinsulator so it seems that thin 2-dimensional materials are the usual way these things are thought of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Superinsulators were originally proposed in two dimensions, and it appears that the experimental efforts have focused on this case. However, it has been argued theoretically that 3D superinsulators can exist; see

- [M. C. Diamantini, L. Gammaitoni, C. A. Trugenberger & V. M. Vinokur: "Vogel-Fulcher-Tamman criticality of 3D superinsulators", *Sci. Rep.* **8**, 15718 (2018)](https://doi.org/10.1038/s41598-018-33765-5).
- [M. C. Diamantini, C. A. Trugenberger & V. M. Vinokur: "Confinement and asymptotic freedom with Cooper pairs", *Commun. Phys.* **1**, 77 (2018)](https://doi.org/10.1038/s42005-018-0073-9)

The "Experimental implications" section of the latter seems to argue that data on InO films are actually more consistent with the 3D mechanism. That said, semi-cursorily browsing the citations to these articles, I did not find any experimental papers on bulk superinsulators.